# No valid credentials provided when i use GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-redis, spring-security-kerberos

I'm trying to write an application using spring-kerberos-core and spring-data-redis.

When i use JdkSerializationRedisSerializer, i get an error in second application

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.demo.app2.CustomUser not found
```

It's logical, because i created my own class that extends User.class of org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User in first app and second app doesn't know about it.

But when i use GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer, i get exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not write JSON: No valid credentials provided (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl["authentication"]->org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceRequestToken["ticketValidation"]->org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosTicketValidation["gssContext"]->sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl["delegCred"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No valid credentials provided (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl["authentication"]->org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceRequestToken["ticketValidation"]->org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosTicketValidation["gssContext"]->sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl["delegCred"])
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:100) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:184) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:133) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:136) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:776) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:649) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:384) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:234) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:197) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:150) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No valid credentials provided (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl["authentication"]->org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceRequestToken["ticketValidation"]->org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosTicketValidation["gssContext"]->sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl["delegCred"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:391) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:351) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:604) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:729) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:604) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:729) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:604) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:729) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:604) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(ObjectMapper.java:3243) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.serialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:98) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: No valid credentials provided
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.getDelegCred(Krb5Context.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.getDelegCred(GSSContextImpl.java:614) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.getDelegCred(SpNegoContext.java:1095) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.getDelegCred(GSSContextImpl.java:614) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:687) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

This is my defentition of Bean:

```
@Bean
    public RedisSerializer<Object> springSessionDefaultRedisSerializer() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new WebJackson2Module());
        return new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(mapper);
    }
```

**UPD1**
Maybe the error i get is consequence of another exception

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Filter threw Exception
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:624) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:150) ~[spring-session-core-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.getWriter(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:249) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 119 common frames omitted
```